# Equivalent formulation of the new operator

Tags: javascript

I'm just beginning to learn JavaScript. It seems to me that

```
B = new A();
```

is the same as,

```
B = Object.create(A.prototype);
A.call(B);
```

Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is my understanding correct?

Yes, that's basically what `new` does.

But you might need to consider some edge cases - when `A` does return an object, the `new` invocation will yield that and not the `this` value. For the exact steps, see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) or [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3127429/1048572).

Also, for some special constructors (not the standard user-declared functions) the behaviour can differ a lot between calls with and without `new`. The built-in constructors (`Array` etc.) are prominent examples.